# Upgrading Custom Site Definition (.wsp) from moss 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: migration, upgrade

I have a custom site definition developed for MOSS 2007. Can I upgrade the same to SharePoint 2010? If yes could someone please post the steps?

Thanks in advance